# Issue with approxQuantile of spark , not recognizing List<String>

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql, quantile

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v in my project with java8.

I need to calculate the quantiles on the some of the (calculated) columns (i.e. `con_dist_1`, `con_dist_2`) of below given dataframe `df`:

```
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+
|  id|     date|   revenue   |con_dist_1| con_dist_2|
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.006628853|         4|0.816039063|
|  10|1/15/2018|   0.01378215|         4|0.082049528|
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.006628853|         4|0.816039063|
|  10|1/15/2018|   0.01378215|         4|0.082049528|
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.014933087|         5|0.034681906|
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.014448282|         3|0.082049528|
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+

List<String> calcColmns = Arrays.asList("con_dist_1","con_dist_2")
```

When I am trying to use first version of `approxQuantile`, i.e.  `approxQuantile(List<String>, List<Double>, double)`
as below

```
List<List<Double>> quants = df.stat().approxQuantile(calcColmns , Array(0.0,0.1,0.5),0.0);
```

**It is giving the error:**

> The method approxQuantile(String, double[], double) in the type
>   DataFrameStatFunctions is not applicable for the arguments
>   (List, List, double)

What is wrong here? I'm doing it in my eclipseIDE. Why it is not invoking `List<String>` even though I'm passing `List<String>`?

**Added snapshot of the API:**

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing a definition of approxQuantile that takes two lists and a double? The API docs I see talk about a String, double[] and double (which is what the error message says).

Comment: @StephenDarlington: `approxQuantile` on multiple columns was added in Spark 2.2.0.

Comment: I haven't used Java in a long while but could the problem be `Array(0.0,0.1,0.5)`? Try to declare the list as `double[] percentiles = {0.0,0.1,0.5};` are see if it works.

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica You should add that as an answer -- that's almost certainly what it is.

Comment: @BdEngineer: I added an answer here and will have some time to take a look at the new question in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it could be due to the use of `Array` in the inputs to the `approxQuantile` function. The simplest fix would be to use arrays for both the columns and the percentiles (this would use the third `approxQuantile` method in the API snapshot.:

```java
String[] calcColmns = {"con_dist_1", "con_dist_2"};
double[] percentiles = {0.0,0.1,0.5};
```

And then call the function:

```java
double[][] quants = df.stat().approxQuantile(calcColmns, percentiles, 0.0);
```